# Yum install Hadoop not found error CENTOS

Tags: hadoop, installation, centos, virtual-machine

I am trying to set up the hadoop environment following the instructions listed in the book Hadoop For Dummies on a virtual machine.

One of step indicates the following code -

```
yum install hadoop\* mahout\* oozie\* hbase\* pig\* hive\* zookeeper\* hue\*
```

When I run that I get the following error -

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# yum install hadoop\*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
 * extras: centos.mirror.crucial.com.au
 * updates: centos.mirror.nsw.au.glovine.com.au
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package hadoop* available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Among all hadoop, zookeeper and hue I got the error saying the package not found. I looked into those mirror sites and I do see that hadoop is not present. Is there any way to force the mirror to some other location?

Edit -

As pointed out below I did try the command to get the repo with the following command -

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo http://archive.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo
```

which is throwing following Connection Refused  error -

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo
--2015-12-30 05:03:09--  http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo
Resolving www.apache.org... 88.198.26.2, 140.211.11.105, 2a01:4f8:130:2192::2
Connecting to www.apache.org|88.198.26.2|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to www.apache.org|140.211.11.105|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to www.apache.org|2a01:4f8:130:2192::2|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Likewise I did try CDH one-click install as pointed out by user1862493 and I am getting the following error

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# wget https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/6/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
--2015-12-30 05:07:49--  https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/6/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm
Resolving archive.cloudera.com... 23.235.41.167
Connecting to archive.cloudera.com|23.235.41.167|:443... failed: Connection refused.
```

yum update worked fine and so is internet within the VM, any help?

Comment: Does the book indicate a yum repository that you should be adding that has these packages? It should.

Comment: Well in the book it was given as - wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo 
http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-0.7.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo which I changed it to - wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo 
http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo . I had got connection refused error, so I manually copied the contents of bigtop.repo data and pasted in the /yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo file and then began the next steps. It didn't help. I just tried now with the same command again but I am getting connection refused error. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the repository first.

```
wget https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/6/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm

yum --nogpgcheck localinstall cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm

 yum clean all
```

Then try to install hadoop components.

Ref http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html#topic_4_4_1_unique_2__p_31_unique_2

Comment: In the wget it says redhat/6/ but I am using CentOS6, will it cause any problem or should I go ahead and run the commands that you have indicated?

Comment: No problem. Redhat/6 will work for both CentOS 6 and RHEL 6. You can run these commands.

Comment: Well, I am getting Connection refused error which is strange as just a while back I had done yum update and it correctly updated everything with Complete status. Any idea how to resolve the error? Also net is working perfectly fine within the vm and in fact I am replying to this on VM only.

Comment: When are you getting connection refused error. Post the command you tried

Comment: Thanks for reply. Posted the errors as part of Edit.

Comment: wget https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/redhat/6/x86_64/cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64.rpm try this and it's clouderas one.

Comment: same error i.e. connection refused which is the error i posed in my edited question :(

Comment: export http_proxy="" 
execute this in the terminal and try again.

Comment: Execute _sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop_ 
and then try the wget command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99280/discussion-between-vkarthik-and-user1862493).