# GPG Key retrieval failed Hadoop Bigtop installation

Tags: hadoop, installation, centos6, bigtop

Following the instructions in the following site - (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/set-up-the-hadoop-environment-with-apache-bigtop.html) or rather from the book Hadoop for Dummies.

Step 3 ran successfully till the end with total download size of 616MB but at the end of it I got into this error -

```
  Total                                           130 kB/s | 616 MB     80:52     
    warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID fa08b173: NOKEY
    Retrieving key from https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/bigtop/KEYS


GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection
```

I ignored that error thinking it would not have any effect. I then proceeded with rest of steps till 4.2 when I started getting the following error -

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode init
sudo: /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode: command not found
```

On searching extensively I had come to realize that reinstalling i.e. running the command yum install hadoop* would fix the issue, which I did and am getting this error -

```
Total size: 198 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID fa08b173: NOKEY
Retrieving key from https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/bigtop/KEYS


GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection
```

I am desperately trying to get the things work as described in the 'Hadoop For Dummies' book but the struggle is enormous. At office system in which I was trying to do, I couldn't go beyond step 1 i.e. getting the repo for which a thread is running - [Yum install Hadoop not found error CENTOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521986/yum-install-hadoop-not-found-error-centos) but this time around this is in my home system still same error. No wonder this book has got worst reviews.

Can someone please guide me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

1) add the following text to the /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo file.

```
[bigtop]
name=Bigtop
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
type=NONE
baseurl=http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.1.0/repos/centos6/
gpgkey=http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.1.0/repos/GPG-KEY-bigtop
```

2) as next step try to install the necessary files again with

```
yum install hadoop\* mahout\* oozie\* hbase\* hive\* hue\* pig\* zookeeper\
```

3) your install will complete now.

cheers, AJ

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the last line in the "/etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo" file and set it like following:
gpgkey=http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-1.0.0/repos/GPG-KEY-bigtop

the problem was because the link of "GPG key" was changed, so you need to change it also

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. However, if you are new to the installation you need to do the followings:

1. do the first step per the book, i.e. "wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo...
2. Edit the bigtop.repo, i.e gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo
3. this will open the bigtop.repo file for editting.
4. Modify the last line using the key above. save and close it.
5. do the second step per the book.

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was a wrong gpgkey path value.

I had prepared local repository and received the same error for Ambari installation.

I had one folder missing in the path.
Adding the missing path fixed the problem for me.

Old (and wrong) value was: 
gpgkey=http://mylocal/repo/ambari/AMBARI-2.4.2.0/centos7/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins

Corrected as:
gpgkey=http://mylocal/repo/ambari/AMBARI-2.4.2.0/centos7/2.4.2.0-136/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins